# Show values from select list jquery

Tags: jquery, html, list, select, selector

The goal i want to achieve is to have a few select lists connected with each other and after the user selects all the paramereters which suit him or her from the select lists i want the script to show the results of selected parameters. Now i know how to create the select lists but i dont know how to show the results.

Here is a part of my code which is still unfinished and you can select only a first few makes and  models, but it should show you what im trying to achieve... im also planning to include selectable year variation and trim version.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xh5uC/1/

```
<div class="articles">
<form method="GET" action=_output.html>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="id_znamka_vozila">Znamka vozila:</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <select name="znamka_vozila" id="id_znamka_vozila">
                    <option value="">Izberite</option>
                    <option value="1">Alfa Romeo</option>
                    <option value="2">Aston Martin</option>
                    <option value="3">Audi</option>
                    <option value="4">Austin</option>
                    <option value="5">Autobianchi</option>
                    <option value="6">Bentley</option>
                    <option value="7">BMW</option>
                    <option value="8">Bugatti</option>
                    <option value="9">Buick</option>
                    <option value="10">Cadillac</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="id_alfaromeo">Model vozila:</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <select name="alfaromeo" id="id_alfaromeo">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Izberite</option>
                    <option value="33">33</option>
                    <option value="75">75</option>
                    <option value="90">90</option>
                    <option value="145">145</option>
                    <option value="146">146</option>
                    <option value="147">147</option>
                    <option value="155">155</option>
                    <option value="156">156</option>
                    <option value="159">159</option>
                    <option value="164">164</option>
                    <option value="166">166</option>
                    <option value="4C">4C</option>
                    <option value="8C">8C</option>
                    <option value="alfasud">Alfasud</option>
                    <option value="alfetta">Alfetta</option>
                    <option value="brera">Brera</option>
                    <option value="crosswagon">Crosswagon</option>
                    <option value="giulia">Giulia</option>
                    <option value="giulietta">Giulietta</option>
                    <option value="GT">GT</option>
                    <option value="GTV">GTV</option>
                    <option value="mito">Mito</option>
                    <option value="rzsz">RZ/SZ</option>
                    <option value="spider">Spider</option>(
                    <option value="sprint">Sprint</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>



$(document).ready(function () {
var $alfaromeoTr = $('#id_alfaromeo').closest('tr').hide();
var $astonmartinTr = $('#id_astonmartin').closest('tr').hide();
var $audiTr = $('#id_audi').closest('tr').hide();
var $bentleyTr = $('#id_bentley').closest('tr').hide();

$('#id_znamka_vozila').change(function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    if (selectedValue === '1') {
        $astonmartinTr.hide();
        $alfaromeoTr.show();
        $bentleyTr.hide();
        $audiTr.hide();

    } else if (selectedValue === '2') {
        $astonmartinTr.show();
        $alfaromeoTr.hide();
        $audiTr.hide();
        $bentleyTr.hide();

    } else if (selectedValue === '3') {
        $audiTr.show();
        $astonmartinTr.hide();
        $alfaromeoTr.hide();
        $bentleyTr.hide();

    } else if (selectedValue === '6') {
        $bentleyTr.show();
        $audiTr.hide();
        $astonmartinTr.hide();
        $alfaromeoTr.hide();



    } else {
        $astonmartinTr.hide();
        $alfaromeoTr.hide();
        $audiTr.hide();
        $bentleyTr.hide();
    }
}
```

So the main question is, how to show the result or a specific page, after user selects make, model (...year, trim, and so on) from the list.

Comment: " ..how to show the result...". What is the desired result?

Comment: I would like for the select list values to work as a filter of my content which will be in a form of classifieds adds... So user will select all the parameters in the select lists and on submit the content would filter in appropriate way.

Comment: I still didn't get what your problem is. The lists are in the form, then why don't you just submit the form and access those values in the server?

Comment: Thats what im trying to achieve, but im not sure what way to achieve it...The form should remember all the values selected from the lists and then filter the content appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to parse the values with JavaScript without using any server-side language (PHP , ASP , etc ) ?

If you do then have a look on this simple example:

Page1.htm

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<META NAME="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft Visual Studio">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
function passValue(val)
{
    if(!val)
    {return false;}

    document.forms[0].action = "Page2.htm?value=" + val;
    return true;
}
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<form onsubmit="passValue(this.first_name.value)" method="post">
<input type="text" name="first_name" size="30">
<input type="submit" value="click me!">
</form>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Page2.htm

```
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<META NAME="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft Visual Studio">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
    var val = window.location.toString().substr(window.location.toString().indexOf('=') + 1);
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("The value was: " + val));
}
</script>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

You can pass the value as part of the action string, thus it becomes part of the location string, which you can check in the called page.

If you wish to pass multiple values, rip the location front end off up to '?' then split() the remainder by '=' to get an array of passed name/value pairs.

Hope this helps